# C# reflection: If ... else?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, system.reflection, memory-address

I'm currently facing new problem with operators. Using following code, I want to make output that would be same as when using `if ... else` pair in C#.

```
var method = new DynamicMethod("dummy", null, Type.EmptyTypes);
var g = method.GetILGenerator();

g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "string");
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "string");
g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(String).GetMethod("op_Equality", new Type[]{typeof(string), typeof(string)}));
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Ceq);
g.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, );

var action = (Action)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
action();

Console.Read();
```

My questions are:

1. How can I get the address of an instruction to pass it as a parameter for branch opcodes?
2. Is there any difference between `BR` and `BR_S`, `Brtrue` and `Brtrue_S`, `Brfalse` and `Brfalse_S` and similar instructions?

Thanks.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the "_S" versions of the branch instructions take a 1-byte rather than 4-byte offset. If you know that your branch will always be within the range available (-128 bytes to +127 bytes), then you will get more compact code by using them, however if you attempt to use them to jump to a label with an offset outside this range, an exception will be thrown when creating the delegate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ILGenerator.ILOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.iloffset) gives you the current offset in the IL stream, if that's what you want. You can use [`DefineLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.definelabel.aspx) and [`MarkLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.marklabel), too, as goric suggested.

The only difference between `brtrue.s` and `brtrue` is that `brtrue.s` is the short version of `brtrue`. `brtrue` uses a 4-byte offset and `brtrue.s` uses a 1-byte offset. The same applies for `brfalse` and `brfalse.s` (and `br`/`br.s`).

Those are not the only short versions of an IL instruction, there are also other short instructions, like `ldc.i4.0` - `ldc.i4.8` for loading integers. Those are mainly useful for generating smaller binaries, but i don't think there is a big difference otherwise.

Answer (score 11):

1. You can use a combination of the [`DefineLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.definelabel) and
   [`MarkLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.marklabel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods to determine the target location of the
   branch. To do so, declare the labels you'll need - something like
   `equal` and `notequal`. Then you can mark the spots in your IL where
   the labels should be present. Once this is done, you can set the
   target of your branch instruction to this label.

   ```
   // Define labels
   Label equal = g.DefineLabel();
   Label notEqual = g.DefineLabel();
   Label endOfMethod = g.DefineLabel();
   // your logic here
   g.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, equal);
   g.MarkLabel(equal);
   // some code if they are equal
   g.MarkLabel(notEqual);
   // some code if they are not equal
   g.MarkLabel(endOfMethod); // this marks the return point
   g.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
   ```
2. The difference between `Br`, `Brtrue`, and `Brfalse` and their `_S`
   counterparts is the length of the jump. The `_S` denotes short form;
   the target instruction is a 1-byte signed offset from the next instruction. In the standard (non-short) form, the target is
   represented by a 4-byte offset.

Answer (score 4):

This is new to me, but from a little searching apparently you get the address by calling

```
Label targetInstruction = g.DefineLabel();
```

at some point beforehand (e.g. before your first `Emit`?), and then

```
g.MarkLabel(targetInstruction);
```

*just before* emitting the line you want to branch *to*. Then this `Label` is the argument to your `Br____` opcode.

The difference between [Br](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brfalse.aspx), [Brtrue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brtrue.aspx) and [Brfalse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brfalse.aspx) is that Br always branches, and the other two pop a value off the stack and only branch if it is true or false respectively. (So yes, there is a big difference!) The _S signifies "short form" but I'm not sure what this means.